# Python Script to generate a random winner based on raffle tickets from .csv file - Keeps adding random list of numbers to end of names

Tags: python, csv, random

I have one file, a .csv file, with two columns. The first is the name of  the person. The second is how many tickets they have.

I want to write a Python script to select a random winning ticket, then match and return the name of the winner.

I managed to get the script working, but there is an issue. The program keeps adding a HUGE string of integers from 1-41 after every name and I can't figure out what's causing it.

```
import csv
import random

file = open("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\raffle.csv")
type(file)
csvreader = csv.reader(file)

rows = []
for row in csvreader:
    rows.append(row)
    rows
    
file.close()

names = []
count = []

counter = 0

for x in rows:
    names.append(x[0])  # Assuming the name is in the first column
    count.append(x[1])

for x in rows:
    trigger = False
    for y in range(len(count)):
        y = str(y)
        if y == ",": 
            trigger = True
            
        if trigger == True: 
            count[counter] += y
        else:
            names[counter] += y
    counter+=1

TotalEntries = 0 # This is the total amount of entries.

count5 = 0 

print(*names)

for x in count:
    TotalEntries += int(count[count5])
    count5+1

winner = random.randint(0, TotalEntries)

countWin = 0
win = ""
countOut = 0


for x in count:
#    # Runs through the list of raffle entries
    for y in range(len(count)):
        if countWin == winner: 
           win = names[countOut]
        countWin+=1
    countOut+=1

winNum = str(winner)
print("The winner is number "+winNum+", "+win)
```

I expected the names list to be filled with peoples' individual names. However, each name has a list of numbers behind it and I can't figure out the source. I am new to Python so any tips are appreciated.

jame01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041 nico01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041 silv01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041 kevy01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041 Chri01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041

Example of list that was returned

I would want a list like

jame
nico
silv
kevy
Chri

Example of input files in .csv
jame,18
nico,19
silv,48
kevy,23
Chri,22

Comment: `if y == ","` can never be true. `y` is a number.

Comment: What do you think `names[counter] += y` does? `y` is a list index converted to a string, and this concatenates it to `names[counter]`. This is creating the long, random number.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do in that loop.

Comment: If you have a list of players and the number of tickets they purchased, you should use a weighted random selection to pick the winner. The number of tickets is the weight.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. For some reason I had no idea y was a number.

Comment: What do you think `for y in range(len(count))` iterates over?

Comment: Thanks for the help Barmar. I thought for y in range(len(count)) was to go through count one by one (if count is 8 items long, I want the loop to run 8 times).

Comment: And that's what it does. It sets `y` to `0`, then `1`, then `2`, and so on.

Comment: I am trying to add all items before the comma into the names list, and all items behind the comma into the number of tickets.

Comment: Before and after what comma? The `csv` module is already splitting the line at commas.

Comment: You did that with `names.append(x[0]) `.

Comment: I'll work on this with the information you gave me, thanks for the tips. I see that adding y to the list is causing the problem - somewhere halfway through I must have forgotten that it wasn't the actual variable itself.

Comment: Don't make separate lists of names and counts. It's almost always easier to keep related data together.

Comment: @Barmar, did you forget anything ?

Answer (score 0):

I got confused as to how you were going about picking a random named based on the total number of names (name*ticket_count for each pair in the CSV).

Given this input CSV:

```
Name,    Ticket count
Alice,              3
Bob,                2
Charlie,            4
Dana,               1
```

From that I'd try to get a *bag of names* like:

```py
['Alice', 'Alice', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Charlie', 'Charlie', 'Charlie', 'Dana']
```

With that you can use the standard lib's random.choice function:

```py
random.choice(bag_of_names)
```

Turning the CSV into the bag of names might look like:

```py
bag_of_names: list[str] = []

with open("input.csv", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    next(reader)  # discard header

    for row in reader:
        name = row[0]
        ticket_ct = int(row[1])

        bag_of_names.extend([name] * ticket_ct)
```

Running that for 1_000 picks, it looks to be picking correctly:

```py
from collections import Counter
from typing import Counter

X = 1_000

c: Counter[str] = Counter()

for _ in range(X):
    c[pick_winner()] += 1

for name, wins in c.most_common():
    print(f"{name:<10} {(wins/X):.2%}")
```

```
Charlie    40.40%
Alice      28.20%
Bob        21.30%
Dana       10.10%
```